# How to get timezones and their respective offset to display on a table view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, timezone

I need to display list of available times zones and their respective offset on a table view like this;

eg: Asia/Colombo - 5

I've got list of times zones using the below code.

```
NSArray *timezoneNames = [NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames];
for (NSString *timesZoneName in [timezoneNames sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)])
{
    NSLog(@"%@",timesZoneName);
}
```

further, I used following code to get the offset from the local time zone.

```
NSTimeZone *timeZones = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
NSInteger offset = [timeZones secondsFromGMT]/3600.0;
NSString *tzname = [timeZones name];
NSLog(@"Time Zone Name: %@ - %ld", tzname, offset);
```

but cannot find a way around how to get the offset values from the names. If anyone can guide me how to do it please ?

Comment: Keep in mind that in the general case, you *can't* map a time zone to a single offset, because many time zones follow different offsets at different times of the year.  `secondsFromGMT` returns the ***current*** offset for the time zone.  See also "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Answer (score 1):

Well you were 1/2 the way there - you need to actually instantiate the `TimeZone` from the name of the timezone in order to calculate it's offset, so code like:

```
NSArray *timezoneNames = [NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames];
for (NSString *timesZoneName in [timezoneNames sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)])
{
    NSTimeZone *timeZone = [[NSTimeZone alloc] initWithName:timesZoneName];
    NSInteger offset = [timeZone secondsFromGMT]/3600.0;
    NSString *tzname = [timeZone name];
    NSLog(@"Time Zone Name: %@ - %ld", tzname, offset);
}
```

i.e. use `[[NSTimeZone alloc] initWithName:timesZoneName]` to get the timezone that's named; then you can get the offset.

Bear in mind that not all timezone offsets are on a whole-hour boundary. For example [India Standard Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Standard_Time) is 5.5 hours off of GMT.